# New Details Section After the end of Details Section A

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I want to add a second details section from another dataset after the *end* of details section A. When there are no more records in Details A, Dection B will show its records.

I have added CrystalReport2 as a subreport to my main report as you can see in the next screenshot. But the subreport doesn't show any records. Plus I would want to calculate a total for each. How can I resolve this?

---

[image]

[image]

---

[image]

```
Private Sub crpt_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim cr As New CrystalReport1
    Dim ds As New DataSet1
    Dim dt As DataTable = ds.DataTable1
    For i As Integer = 0 To mrpt.DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        dt.Rows.Add(mrpt.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value, mrpt.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value, mrpt.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value, mrpt.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value, mrpt.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value, mrpt.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value, mrpt.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(9).Value, mrpt.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value)
    Next
    cr.SetDataSource(dt)
    cr.SetParameterValue("mmonth", mrpt.ComboBox3.SelectedItem & " / " & mrpt.ComboBox4.SelectedItem)
    cr.SetParameterValue("cno", mrpt.ComboBox1.SelectedItem)
    cr.SetParameterValue("ctyp", mrpt.ComboBox2.SelectedItem)
    cr.SetParameterValue("tot", mrpt.TextBox1.Text)
    Dim cr2 As New CrystalReport2
    Dim ds2 As New SubDataSet2
    Dim dt2 As DataTable = ds2.DataTable1
    For i As Integer = 0 To mrpt.DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        dt2.Rows.Add(mrpt.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value, mrpt.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value, mrpt.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value, mrpt.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value)
    Next
    cr2.SetDataSource(dt2)

    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cr
End Sub
```

Comment: what if you add `CrystalReportViewer1.refresh()` at the end of the event?

Comment: Does Report2 function if you run it *outside* of the main report?

Comment: @4444 yes it works

Comment: @romulus001 tried and didn't work

Comment: Odds are if the report functions outside but *not* inside, the subreport isn't properly linked. The parameters it receives are either incorrect/incomplete or *too* restrictive causing no data to pull in.